# A expressão "Velho Ditado" veio da frase "Velho Deitado"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, português-brasileiro, ditados

Em uma conversa , entramos em um debate interessante, de onde surgiu a expressão "Velho Ditado", a origem seria apenas conceitual ou houve um acontecimento histórico que deu origem a essa expressão? Ou uma modificação temporal da frase "Velho Deitado"?

Comment: "Velho ditado" como em "velho provérbio"?

Comment: Sim @Jacinto, não tinha pensado em "provérbio", mas seria como.

Comment: Vi um trocadilho com essas duas expressões num gibi do Chico Bento.

Comment: A Magda, personagem do programa humorístico "Sai de Baixo" que usava a expressão " já dizia o velho deitado" para se referir ao um "velho ditado".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Ditado*** não tem que ver com *deitado*, mas sim com [*ditar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/ditar) no sentido de prescrever ou de dizer em voz alta para que se escreva. Veja-se [***ditado*** no Aulete digital:](http://www.aulete.com.br/ditado)

> **Substantivo masculino 1.** Ação de ditar algo para que outro escreva.
> **2.** O texto que se dita; a escrita feita por ditado (1).
> **3.** Frase popular cujo conteúdo encerra um ensinamento; PROVÉRBIO
> **Adjetivo 4.** Lido ou dito em voz alta para ser escrito **5.** Que é prescrito: *regras ditadas pelo Ministério da Saúde.* **6.** Sugerido ou inspirado por alguém ou por algo.: *normas ditadas pelo bom-senso.*
> [F.: Do lat. dictatum.]

A significado relevante em ***velho ditado*** é o (3), «frase popular cujo conteúdo encerra ensinamento,» e está associado também ao significado (5) de coisa prescrita, pois um ditado encerra normalmente um conselho. A palavra *velho* é aqui apenas um adjetivo: o ditado é velho, antigo. Possivelmente adjetiva-se assim o ditado porque as pessoas dão valor à sabedoria antiga.

***Ditado***, tirando o significado de provérbio, é hoje imediatamente associado a exercício escolar. Mas no século XVI tinha um sentido mais vasto. Nesta passagem é apenas uma frase que alguém queria que escrevessem na sua sepultura, o que hoje chamaríamos [*epitáfio*](http://www.aulete.com.br/epit%C3%A1fio) (*por* significa *para*, *quë* é *quem*):

> Sobre minha ssepoltura depoys de sser enterrado se ponha este ***ditado*** por sse ver minha ventura. Aquy jaz o mays leal macho rruço que naçeo a quy jaz quë nam comeo a sseu dono hû soo rreal. ([Garcia de Resende](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garcia_de_Resende), [*Cancioneiro Geral*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancioneiro_Geral), 1516.)

Chamava-se também antigamente ***ditado*** ao título com que se apresentava alguém importante:

> He gramde senhor, e homem de muita justiça, e de gramdes supitos; e este he seu ditado, Crisnarao macação, rey dos reys, senhor dos senhores mayores da Imdia, senhor dos tres mares e da terra [(Chronica dos Reis de Bisnaga, 1500-40.)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronica_dos_Reis_de_Bisnaga)
>
> Seu ***ditado*** nas cartas, em vida d'elrrei dom Fernando, era este: "Dona Lionor pella graça de Santa Maria rrainha de Portugall e do Algarve" ([Fernão Lopes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern%C3%A3o_Lopes), *Crónica de D. Fernando*, 1434-51.)

As ocorrências mais antigas que consegui encontrar de *ditado* no sentido que mais nos interessa aqui são do século XVII. Parece que também nessa época se valorizava a antiguidade dos ditados:

> É cousa triste viver com todos, e julgar os que vos hão-de julgar, sendo certo, como antigo, aquele costume ou ***ditado*** que a justiça todos a querem, ninguém em sua casa e menos em si mesmo. ([Francisco Manuel de Melo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Manuel_de_Melo), *Apolo*, cerca de 1640.)
>
> Diz um antigo ditado: "Quem não tem marido, não tem amigo". Diz outro: "Quem tem molher, tem o que ha mistér". ([Francisco Manuel de Melo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Manuel_de_Melo), [*Carta da Guia de Casados*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_de_Guia_de_Casados), 1650.)